Error conexión a BD SQL Server alojada en Azure con Kotlin Android
Estoy teniendo el siguiente error al querer conectar mi aplicación Android a la base de datos SQL Server alojada en Azure:
Process: com.example.aplicacionconexionazuredemo, PID: 4968
java.lang.AssertionError: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6880)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:6844)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.ensurePayload(IOBuffer.java:6816)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readBytes(IOBuffer.java:7168)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:953)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:943)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1207)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:1193)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:945)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:909)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:731)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1855)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3814)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3402)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:3211)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
    at com.example.aplicacionconexionazuredemo.MainActivity$connectToDatabase$2.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:93)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:99)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:811)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:715)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:702)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a8746b0, Dispatchers.Main]

Y no sé por qué no me permite conectarme a la BD a través de la aplicación Android.
Espero me puedan ayudar.
Gracias.
